# Android Autofill Service Not Working in Chrome

Tags: android, autofill

onFillRequest of AutofillSerive is not triggered on chrome browser in android. I checked in another browser like firefox, it is working fine there. How app like Dashlane support autofill in chrome?

Comment: In 2023: https://www.reddit.com/r/androiddev/comments/qvjgjg/comment/hkyvl4u + https://developer.android.com/reference/android/service/autofill/AutofillService#compatibility-mode

Answer (score 3):

It is a bug in Chrome. The fix should land in Chrome 89.

https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1151614

https://github.com/bitwarden/mobile/issues/489

Comment: ok..lets wait for update...but how app like dashlane is working

Comment: 101 and the problem still around